# Can I lay laminate flooring over top of existing linoleum?

Tags: laminate, linoleum

I'm interested in laying laminate flooring over the top of existing intact linoleum.  First, any problems with that?  Secondly, there are unfortunately also uneven spots under the linoleum that causes ridges which are discernable even as you walk across it.  I have gone as far as taking a level and running along the spots to see if I was just out of my mind.. nope.  Are these ridges something that I need to address or can I lay laminate over the top of them?  How can I go about leveling them if needed?  Self-leveling compound/concrete?

Comment: I see three questions, each dependant on a positive answer to the previous..  - "Can I Lay over top?" If the answer is no, the next two are irrelevant. If yes, then - "Do I need to deal with ridges" becomes active. Again a no dooms the third to irrelevancy.  A yes makes the -"How do I deal with ridges" active.   This should be broken up into seperate questions.

Comment: The answer to the question "*Can I lay laminate flooring over top of existing linoleum?*", is yes. The answer to "***SHOULD** I lay laminate flooring over top of existing linoleum?*", is debatable, but likely NO.

Comment: Is it really linoleum? Vinyl tile tends to be far more common both in both residential commercial construction over the last three or four decades and older construction may have asbestos tile. I would suggest that removing the old tile should be considered prep for installing a self-leveling compound. The investment of time and energy is enough to justify the additional work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is "look at the instructions for the laminate", and see what they say. If you have old-school hard laminate (like you find in schools/government buildings/grocery stores), then it's a nice hard surface and it is fine. If it is resilient flooring (kitchen vinyl), then the answer is read the instructions.

If you have big ridges, I'd probably just grind them down with an angle grinder.

Comment: If it is old asbestos tile, the grinder would probably be a bad idea - as in significantly worse than removing the tile, which may not be such a hot idea in and of itself.